# Changing the view within the Android Tab Widget

Tags: java, android, tabwidget

So I have my tab layout working as demonstrated in the [Android example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistActivity.class);

// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

// Do the same for the other tabs
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Now, in one of the tab's activities I've declared a button and would like to bring in a new view. If I create a new intent it will push a new view and the tabs are gone. Is it possible to switch the currently selected view with a new view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is very much possible .. You have to use ActivityGroup for this purpose..

Instead of Adding a activity to a TabHost.. You have to add ActivityGroup..
Each Activity Group is having its Activity..

THis is simple to implement

I have the same issue but got it totaly RESOLVED Check The Following Link

http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

Its The Solution For Me . Hope It will Help You as Well

Comment: This worked great, but do you know how to call the onKeyDown method within this class?

Comment: This is a tough work .. But very much possible... Override methods in your activity and return true and same method of TabGroupActivity Parent CLass make it return to false...

This whole funda is associated with how true and false are returning from onKeyDown Method. Try its various combination it will help. this is As far as I Know