# How to use ActivityGroup/ViewFlipper?

Tags: android, android-widget

In my application I want to use 4 tabs and each tab will have more than one screen. So I tried to get this and found there are two ways to do this:

1. Use `ViewFlipper` inside every tab.
2. Use `ActivityGroup` in tabs.

However, I'm not sure which will be efficient and easy way to do this since I'm a newbie in Android. So please help me.

Please post me some link where I can get sample code related to `ActivityGroup`.

Comment: i got some help from here http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activities are self-contained parts of your app, views are used together when they display similar type of data/behavior.

For example if your tab 1 is taking a picture and your tab 2 is showing a map and your tab 3 is sending an email then you're better of using activities as the action are completely different, with different layouts and different behaviors.

If tab 1 is a listview with an rss feed from techcrunch, tab 2 is a rss feed from StackOverFlow and tab 3 is a rss feed from bbc news then use a viewflippers : Same behavior, same actions

Answer (score 1):

THis is simple to implement

Adding Activity Group will be more preffered then adding View Flipper. By this all the code and activity contents are separated and in more manageable form plus its a stable thing to use

I have the same issue but got it totaly RESOLVED Check The Following Link

http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

[Changing the view within the Android Tab Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734539/changing-the-view-within-the-android-tab-widget/4734670#4734670)

Its The Solution For Me . Hope It will Help You as Well

Comment: Your Welcome @warrior . This the way this stackoverflow works. Asking specific programming problem and on receiving good direction answer accepting the one that helps you out the most. so that others can also get the right direction and benefit of a free Coding Community is availed to all members of its member.